# Edit Div in Context Menu Not Grabbing Correct Div (CKEditor v. 4.6.2)

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, ckeditor

I am running into an issue where the CKEditor is not grabbing the correct `div` when I right click and click 'Edit Div' from the context menu with the below HTML objects. For example, when I right click on the 'well' `div` and I get 'jumbotron' returned on the Edit Div modal window. I also get the 'container' `div` when I right click and edit the 'panel' `div`. Is this a known issue? Any workarounds for this?

```
<div class="container">
<div class="jumbotron">
<h1>Jumbotron</h1>

<p>Sample text here </p>
</div>

<div class="well">this is a well</div>

<div class="panel">this is a panel</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there is a slight mistake in the question as clicking on both `well` and `panel` divs will return the `container` div.

The reason for it is that **plugin you are referring to ([Div Container Manager](https://ckeditor.com/addon/div)), works with div containers and not with plain divs**. By div container I mean a div having child paragraphs or child divs inside. Context menu is in fact being only shown for `container` and `jumbotron` divs. You may have gotten the idea that it should work with `panel` and `well` but if e.g. `panel` div was not nested inside the `container` context menu for editing/removing div would not be shown.

**The editor uses this code to get the outermost div**: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/div/plugin.js#L126-L131

Please paste your HTML into the editor, open the browser console, click inside the `panel` div and execute the code below in the console. You will notice that `container` div is returned.

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1; 
var path = editor.elementPath( editor.getSelection().getStartElement() ); editor.elementPath( path.blockLimit ).contains( 
function( node ) {
return node.is( 'div' ) && !node.isReadOnly();
});
```

To summarize - this is how this plugin works.